# Integral of exponential of Gaussian process has a known distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

If $f(x)$ is Gaussian process, i.e.,

$$
f(x) = GP [m(x), \kappa(x, x')]
$$

can we say anything about the distribution of the integral of the exponential of this, i.e.,

$$
F = \int e^{f(x)} dx 
$$

or, if it's more helpful, the logarithm $ln[F]$?

---

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570858/integral-of-a-gaussian-process-has-gaussian-distribution/1129990) previous post uses the Riemann sum to show the distribution of the integral of a Gaussian process is Gaussian, though I've had no luck applying the same idea to the above problem. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092879/distribution-of-integral-of-exponential-gaussian-process) post discusses a similar problem but for the complex case. [A paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511517.pdf) linked in that post discusses the distribution of $\int_0^T exp(u X(t)) dt$ where $X(t)$ is Brownian motion, though I'm not sure I understand the connection between Gaussian processes and Brownian motion enough for this to help.

Comment: A hint. If $f(x)$ is Gaussian, $exp(f(x))$ is lognormal. An integral is a sum. What is the distribution of the sum of lognormal variables?